# Ampps rejects my Mac user password when I open it

Tags: 64-bit, passwords, macos-catalina, ampps

I installed AMPPS using the "website" and "brew cask" but in both times when I enter the mac user password it gives "the password you entered is incorrect"

I thought i typed the password wrong or something
so I typed it in a text file and copied it the passowrd field and to check if I typed the password wrong again pasted for `sudo` as well

does anyone have the same problem or know a solution

[stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59700420/4640936)

Comment: same on mine...

Comment: I tried following what other users did on the official forum, but no success so far https://www.softaculous.com/board/index.php?as=ksrs3kletqce9mgkngx8g2b8xyirlhtr&tid=15991&title=AMPPS64_is_unusable_on_Catalina

Answer (score 0):

I'm having same problem when starting Ampps which has just been downloaded.
It's not caused by password with special characters.

Instead, **right click** your Ampps.app, click "Open" to start Ampps. Now you can enter your password. Check "Remember" so next time you can start Ampps normally without asking for password.